# Shrink to fit a canvas in JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

My simple question that I can't figure out is how to make a canvas in JavaScript a native width/height, then scale and center it.

I want to do this for my Three.js project (had to throw that in there just in case you can do this with Three.js), and I want to make it fair for other users with different screen sizes.

Here's what mine does now:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

What I'm trying to say is that the canvas is always the window size.

I want to make it a native size (1440px * 900px), but scale to fit the window size (and center).

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image: Image 3]

While the blue part is the canvas and the white space is the window.

The height should fit to the window, or if the width goes out of the window then the width should fit the window.

And last but not least I just need to center it. I can do this easily but I need help fitting the specific size and scaling.

This is what resizes it to the window size:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  weaponCamera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  weaponCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  weaponRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

I have tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515707/scaling-a-javascript-canvas-game-properly), but that is for 2d canvases.

I made my own prototype by doing this:

```js
let width = 1440;
let height = 900;

let scaleX = Math.max(window.innerWidth / width, window.innerHeight / height);
let scaleY = Math.min(window.innerWidth / width, window.innerHeight / height);
let scale = (scaleX + scaleY) / 2;

renderer.domElement.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
```

But this makes it too small and not really native-based size.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the object-fit css property to the canvas? Like so,

```
canvas { width:100vw; height:100vh; object-fit:contain; }
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn’t do anything. I don’t know what the problem could be